# Puppet 6: PuppetDB won't start because of clojure/java errors

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent, puppetdb

I've searched far and wide, and I just simply can't get it to work. I've searched everything I could find which contained "puppetdb", but without success.

I have followed the documentation, and I started writing a quick step to step guide for our company to follow. My rought guide can be found here https://pastebin.com/YfUNXmjX.

Everything seems to go smoothly, but as soon as I run this command:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet resource service puppetdb ensure=running enable=true
```

it fails. Starting it with systemctl makes it hang forever.
When I run the above command, this is what it spits out: https://pastebin.com/c6nTQ6K5

It should also be noted that I've never used puppet before, and am simply a devops in training, trying to learn new technology. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel like this one gives better information: https://pastebin.com/3sGHgLPe

Comment: Well, got a *tiny* bit further by removing an accidental "database.ini" file, which was even spelt wrong; it complained about "lcoalhost", which is also spelt wrong. Deleting that file removed one error. Now I'm down to "Configuration path '/etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d' must exist and must be readable". My problem is just that it's has 777 permissions (in a try to resolve that issue), and as you can see, it didn't. https://pastebin.com/YdyMvT9j

Comment: It later complained about the ssl folder not being readable. I set to permissions to 755, just to be sure (I know this probably shouldn't be like this, but this is a test environment, so don't mind it). Now it's been hanging for a bit, so I suppose I've done *something* right.

Comment: After changing permissions on certain directories and a restart, starting puppetdb works, but now puppet and puppetserver are gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand the error messages, but I started reading them and studying them. I had also apparently forgotten some dependencies and hardware requirements.

1. I was running on **1** core (xen VM), and puppet requires **2**; this is fixed in the domU's configuration file.
2. I had installed **no dependencies**. Installing those fixed some issues.
   Information about *hardware requirements* and *dependencies* can be found [**here**](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/system_requirements.html).
3. I had set wrong **permissions**, **owners**, and **groups** on various directories and files. Set the right permissions, and make sure it's all **`puppet:puppet`**.
4. Check for spelling errors in files and file names. I had for example mistyped the port to **5132**; the correct port is **5432**.
5. The best way to pick up changes is to restart the puppet master, that is with the `reboot` command. Thereafter start **puppetdb** ***first***, and *then* start puppet (called `puppet-agent` instead of `puppet` when installing) and puppetserver.